# How to get json response from controller in cake php from the socket.io

Tags: php, json, node.js, cakephp, socket.io-1.0

I want the json response as it is done using ajax request by passing the parameter for a given url. I want to do something similar in the node.js. Is there any library or ajax can be called inside node.js or else. Thanks!

my ajax request is the following

```
var url = '<?php echo URL."ShiftUsers/shiftResponseNotifications/"."'+orgId+'"."/"."'+boardManagerList+'".".json";?>';

                    setInterval(function()
                        {

                            $.ajax(
                                {
                                    url:url, 
                                    datatype:'jsonp',
                                    type:'post', 
                                    success:function(response)
                                    {
                                    }
                                });
```

I want the same request from the node.js. like some

```
io.sockets.on( 'connection', function ( socket ) {
                 //some calls to api and emit....
              });
```

I am novice at this.

Comment: Have you tried some code? If yes, share your code too.

Comment: sorry, i dont to where to start.Thanks!

Comment: There are plenty of AJAX libraries available for node.js, like [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) or just use node.js's [built in http module](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback)